# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'string'

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code in which 2 digits are checked if they are digits or not. Everything works fine when input are digits. Problem occurs when one digit is treated as str. Then I got an error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'any str typed in keyboard'`

Here is my code:

```
def dividingResult(x, y):
    result = x/y
    return result

def checkDigit1(x):
    if x.isdigit():
        return x
    else:
        print('It is not a digit')
        programStart()

def checkDigit2(y):
    if y.isdigit():
        return y
    else:
        print('It is not a digit')
        programStart()

def programStart():
    print("type digit 1")
    digit1 = input()

    checkDigit1(digit1)

    print("type digit 2")
    digit2 = input()

    checkDigit2(digit2)

    print(dividingResult(int(digit1), int(digit2)))

programStart()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here  `print(dividingResult(int(digit1), int(digit2)))`.

You are only checking for digits inside the functions `checkDigit1` and `checkDigit2` and the above line is not inside them. You are not setting any condition for that.

Here is the whole code;

```
def dividingResult(x, y):
    result = x/y
    return result

def checkDigits(x, y):
    if x.isdigit() and y.isdigit():
        return x, y
    else:
        print('These are not digits')
        programStart()
        return False


def programStart():
    print("type digit 1")
    digit1 = input()

    print("type digit 2")
    digit2 = input()

    checkDigits(digit1, digit2)
    if checkDigits:
        print(dividingResult(int(digit1), int(digit2)))
programStart()
```

Please comment if you want explanation